# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'?

Tags: c#, type-conversion

what ever I select any name available in combo box it should reflects on text box.
I m beginner pls pls help me to solve it

```
public class product
{
    public int proid { set; get; }
    public string prodname { set; get; }
    public int unitprice { set; get; }

}
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)        
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"server=xxxx-PC; database= sample; integrated security= true");
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from tblproduct ", con);
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    product prod = new product();
    while(dr.read())
    {
        prod.proid = dr[0].ToString();
        prod.prodname = dr[1].ToString();
        prod.unitprice = dr[2].ToString();
        textBox2.Text = proid;
        textBox3.Text = prodname;
        textBox4.Text = unitprice;
    } 
}
```

With error:

```
Error   :   The name 'prodname' does not exist in the current context
Error   :   Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'`improved formatting`
```

Comment: it should be textBox3.Text = prod.prodname;

Comment: Seriously? It takes two seconds to Google the answer.... here I'll do it for you... https://www.google.com/search?q=convert+string+to+int+c%23&oq=convert+string+to+&aqs=chrome.3.57j0j5j0j62j60.6910j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: yes error cleared for prodname thank you. kindly let me know for prodid and unitprice. it will be help for me

Comment: prod.proid = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]);textBox2.Text = prod.proid.ToString();         now the error is "Input string was not in a correct format." how to solve??pls help me

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're trying to set a `String` value to an `Int32` property without any explicit cast or conversion, and no implicit cast is defined:

```
// ...
public int proid { set; get; }
// ...

// ...
prod.prodid = dr[0].ToString();
// ...
```

Depending on the actual type of `dr[0]`, you could possible use [`GetInt32()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getint32.aspx) and similar methods instead of the [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y64yaah2.aspx) and `.ToString()`:

```
prod.proid = dr.GetInt32(0);
```

Though, if the column is nullable in SQL, you'll need to test for `NULL`s with [`IsDbNull()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.isdbnull.aspx) and provide a replacement value:

```
prod.proid = dr.IsDbNull(0) ? default(int) : dr.GetInt32(0);
```

The default value can only be `null` to match SQL if the `class`' properties are changed to [`int?`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx):

```
public int? proid { set; get; }
```

Or, specify the cast or conversion separately:

```
prod.proid = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0].ToString());
```

But, since the goal seems to be to update text boxes, you could skip the detour with the `product`, matching the `String` value with a `String` property:

```
textBox2.Text = dr[0].ToString();
```

Comment: while (dr.Read())
            {
                produ prod = new produ();
                prod.proid = dr.GetInt32(0);
                prod.unitprice = Convert.ToInt32(dr[2]);
                prod.prodname = dr[1].ToString();
                textBox3.Text = prod.prodname;
                textBox2.Text = dr[0].ToString();
                textBox4.Text = prod.unitprice.ToString();
              
            }Specified cast is not valid near     prod.proid = dr.GetInt32(0);

Comment: @pooja What SQL type is the column for `dr[0]`? If it's an [`INT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx) and doesn't contain any `NULL` values (in any rows), `GetInt32()` shouldn't have an issue with casting. Note: You also have to match the byte-size – `INT` with `GetInt32()`, `BIGINT` with [`GetInt64()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getint64.aspx) and `long`, `TINYINT` with [`GetByte()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getbyte.aspx), etc.

Comment: thank you but i m getting error as input not in correct format near prod.proid = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0].ToString());

Comment: @pooja [You'll get a `FormatException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b.aspx) if the "*value does not consist of an optional sign followed by a sequence of digits (0 through 9).*" And, it means the column for `dr[0]` has at least one value that .NET can't recognize as an integer. But, as you haven't shared many details about the `tblproduct` itself, I can't really help any further since there's an apparent mismatch of types/values between your code and the table data.

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitly convert your String to an int:

```
int i;

bool succeeded = int.TryParse(string, out i);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring  Product as

```
public class product
    {
        public int proid { set; get; }    //Integer
        public string prodname { set; get; }
        public int unitprice { set; get; }
    }
```

and assigning string to it as  `prod.proid = dr[0].ToString();`

Secondly, `textBox2.Text = proid;` statement has the error in some cases. e.g. null or some other formatting. You can use TryParse() for it as below:

```
int productId = 0;
 Int.TryParse(string, out productId)
 textBox2.Text =productId.ToString() ;
```

Answer (score 0):

A separate issue you may run into once you get the code compiling is with the SqlDataReader: you have to call dr.Read() before trying to access dr[0]

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read.aspx

Answer (score -1):

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

 {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"server=xxxx-PC; database= sample;       integrated security= true");
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from tblproduct ", con);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            product prod = new product();

            // need to convert to integer, coz prodid is int
            prod.proid = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0].ToString());
            prod.prodname = dr[1].ToString();
            prod.unitprice = Convert.ToInt32(dr[2].ToString());

            // need to convert to string, textbox gets only string type
            // prod... => object_name.member_name
            textBox2.Text = prod.proid.ToString();

            // or u can u do: ..= prod.prodid+""; => this convert to str automatically             
            textBox3.Text = prod.prodname.ToString();
            textBox4.Text = prod.unitprice.ToString();
}
```

Comment: thank you but i m getting error as  input not in correct format near prod.proid = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0].ToString());